# Исходящие запросы TCP

Tags: tcp

меня беспокоят наличие исходящих соединений программы, для работы которой нет надобности в интернет соединении. Как понять что это за запросы? Куда ведет адрес? 
Может ли это быть критично для моей конфиденциальности?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На скриншоте что? Вывод команды netstat из Windows?

Comment: Очевидно, что программа проверяет наличие обновлений.

Comment: Очевидно что оно сливает куда то данные, днс не разу не Майкрософт, программу удалить, компьютер по чистить :) можно включить tcpdump и захватить поток в файл, чтоб посмотреть чего она туда льет..

Comment: @iluxa1810 Как ни странно, не очевидно. Любой может создать домен вида update.microsoft.com.pupkin-vasiliy.net. В данном случае, это CDN Akamai Technologies, а что за ним стоит, непонятно.

Comment: Текст лучше писать текстом, а не картинкой.